# revoke or close the current platform channel in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to close or revoke the current channel between dart and native plugin all that happened is app crashing, I tried to call different channels with the same name to close the current one but it sees them the same channel and also crashed with exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException Reply already submitted"
Is there any solution for my problem ?